# How to show javascript file to all users now devise added rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Once upon a time my single page rails app showed a nice d3.js graph. This was derived from a database and showed all the users in the app.

Then I applied devise. The intention was for the same d3.js svg (called graph.js in the app) to show up in all users screene

I changed the users table so that it accommodated the devise fields as well as my own.
Now the d3.js won't show and I don't know why.Everything else shows on the page however including other javascript files in the same assets folder does show up. Debugging in the chrome browser shows there are no javascript errors. I'm not sure where to begin with finding out why the javascript doesn't show up

The code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Graph</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dcsns_dark.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dcsns_light.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dcsns_wall.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/d3.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bchart.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/d3.v3.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/graph.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/user.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="jACMIxlQrneyrGGgGKtYZaK587ab6/W6KKQD7YyU+Es=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-full">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">

          <h1>big.f</h1>

        </div>

      </div> 
      </div>

      <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
  Logged in as <strong>sebastiz@example.com</strong>.
  <a class="navbar-link" href="/users/edit">Edit profile</a> |
  <a class="navbar-link" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>

  <script src="/assets/javascripts/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  

  <script> $(".alert").addClass("in").fadeOut(4500);

/* swap open/close side menu icons */
$('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function(){
    // toggle icon
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
//initializeGraph();
</script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span4">
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <div id="chart"><script src="/assets/graph.js?body=1"></script></div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="span4">
    <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="well">
                <h2>Profile</h2>
                <p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>

<div class='profile-content'></div>

                <div id="FBDiv"></div>
                </p>
             </div>
            <div id="chart_1"><script src="/assets/bchart.js?body=1"></script></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly including `d3.v3.min.js` from your body?  That doesn't look right - it already is getting included in the head.

Comment: I edited out your email so that you don't get spammed.

Comment: Thanks for deleting email. @Steve- I've removed it from the body but its the same result

Comment: Are you using Rails 3.1+?  If so, you should consider leveraging the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to manage static assets.

Comment: Ah. I figured it out. I had emptied the database so there was no data to show. Duh. Works now its repopulated